# I need some assistance with understanding これといった in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, conjugations

> 身体を起こし、手足が**これといった**支障もなく動くのを確かめた。

[This article](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/understanding-%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) says that これといった means the following.

> "Since 「これといった」 is always used in conjunction with a negative expression containing 「ない」, the basic idea of a phrase/sentence containing 「これといった」 would automatically be something like "there is nothing one could point one's finger and say 'This is it!'

But in my sentence I can't find the ない, other than もなく, which is the continuative form of もない. Because its in the continuative form, I doubt that it counts as the required ない to make the above explanation for これといった applicable to my sentence.

And because there is no negative verb, as far as I can tell at least, I can't use the definition [I found here](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F) on Jisho.org.

これといった

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of もなく is wrong. なく, even in the 連用形 or any other form, is still ない, so it is perfectly acceptable to use it with これといった. Also the も acts as an emphasizer here.

> 身体を起こし、手足が*これといった*支障も**なく**動くのを確かめた。 = I checked if my limbs will move **without** *any special* problem by standing up.

Comment: How can you tell that the も in もなく is a emphasizer-も that's separate from なく, and not the も that makes the beginning of もなく, I.E. もない that means "without any", in もない 's continuative form?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey もない is always two words (も + ない). Looks like you somehow learned もない as if it were a single word, but that's not correct. At least monolingual dictionaries do not have an entry for もない.